# Lines aesthetics do not fit what I specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot 2 variables using ggplot2, and set different colors for them. It works fine for the first one but the second gives a random result with another color and a thicker line even thouth its size is specified. Also the size and color values are added in the legend, I don't know why. Do you have any idea why this happens and how to avoid it?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(test, mapping=aes(x=date, y=HU_Q,), size=1, color="blue") +
  geom_line(test, mapping=aes(x=date, y=(SWI_Q*100),size=1, color= "green"))
```

[image: The resulting image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because you’ve put the second `color = "green"` *inside the aesthetics*.

Inside aesthetics, the value isn’t interpreted as a specific colour but rather as a distinct input variable. The color which ‘ggplot2’ assigns to this variable depends on the colour scheme (which you haven’t set); its *values* are mapped arbitrarily.

Changing the second `geom_line` to the following will make the line green:

```
geom_line(test, mapping = aes(x = date, y = SWI_Q * 100), size = 1, color = "green")
```